# Launch apk compilation and starting from command line or shortcut

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I am starting an Android project with PhoneGap; I am using Eclipse with ADT plugin, the point is that I do web development for my mobile app because I use PhoneGap, and I use Visual Studio for that (yeah I'm not joking : I know it well, it works well).

The problem is that everytime i want to test my app I have to go on eclipse and use the run button. Is there anyway I could build a shortcut for compiling my app and run it (on my android device) ? Like some command line eclipse, or something with Android SDK ? I use Windows 7.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You may create *.bat file with every needed command 
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

 P.S: This guide may also be helpful http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html#start